# Ajax POST data array is always empty

Tags: jquery, arrays, servlets, parameter-passing

I am having a slight problem with ajax and Java servlet.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'sampleURL',
    type: 'POST',
    data:data,
    success: function(response){ },
    error: function(){}
});
```

My data object is made like this

```
{name:'name',vars:[array]}
```

My vars array exists, and is not empty.

When i try to do this thing in servlet

```
System.out.println(request.getParameter("name")); //it does print name
```

But when I try to print parameter vars it is always null.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well It is a bit weird for this to be needed but if I created object like this

```
{name:'name',JSON.stringify(vars:[array])}
```

Param vars is not null anymore and I can use it as JSON

Answer (score 0):

in .js(java script)

```
var variable="test";
$.ajax({
    url: baseUrl + "nameController/test1",
    async: false,
    data: {val: variable},
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (dat) {
        console.log(dat);
    }
});
```

you create nameController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "test1", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
String checkRoomStatusReservation(@RequestParam(value = "val", required = true) String parse) {
    System.out.println("parse"+parse);
    //value from parse=test
return parse;
}
```

you can try this